# PHP making class v7 compatible

Tags: php, class, compatibility

I have an old class file that since updating my PHP version to 7 now reports errors.

"Methods with the same name as their class will not be
constructors in a future version of PHP"

I have read several guides and I tried what was suggested:

https://cweiske.de/tagebuch/php4-constructors-php7.htm

Currently my edited changes to the class are as follows:

```
class tFPDF {

     public function __construct() {

     }

     var $unifontSubset;
     var $page;               // current page number
     ....
     var $PDFVersion;         // PDF version number

     function tFPDF($orientation='P', $unit='mm', $size='A4') {

          $this->StdPageSizes = array('a4'=>array(595.28,841.89));

     }

     function _getpagesize($size) {

          $size = strtolower($size);
          if(!isset($this->StdPageSizes[$size]))
               $this->Error('Unknown page size: '.$size);
          }

     }

     function AddPage($orientation='', $size=''){

          $size = $this->_getpagesize($size);

     }

}
```

Then in my codebase the following is called:

$pdf->AddPage('P', 'A4');

This throws the error: Unknown page size: a4

So it seems that the initial class that sets the $this->StdPageSizes property is not run or being read. This worked fine in the older version of PHP so I am guessing that I am missing a fundamental step.

I have also looked at an updated version of the class which might work with php& but it seems that it is no longer supported.

Can anyone help me make my class compatiable, thanks!

Comment: Read the section "A real fix" in your link carefully

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your old-style constructor signature doesn't match the `__construct` signature, so when your code calls the constructor, the `$this->StdPageSizes` array doesn't get initialized.

You can fix this by moving your old constructor code to the `__construct` method:

```
public function __construct($orientation = 'P', $unit = 'mm', $size = 'A4') 
{
    $this->StdPageSizes = array('a4' => array(595.28, 841.89));
}
```

To keep from repeating your constructor code, you can call the `__construct` method from your old constructor:

```
public function tFPDF($orientation = 'P', $unit = 'mm', $size = 'A4') 
{
    self::__construct($orientation, $unit, $size);
}
```

Comment: really appreciate the solution, I need to study up on this, had me stumped for several hours

Answer (score 1):

Only the construtor is missing.

But creating a new object extending the old concept would be more to the future. Also e.g. if updates will follow of the old stuff. :)

```
class tFPDFv7 
    extends tFPDF 
{
    public function __construct($orientation='P', $unit='mm', $size='A4') {
        $this->tFPDF($orientation, $unit, $size);
    }
}
```